# Rspec STDIN gets

Tags: ruby, rspec, io, user-input, specifications

How can I use gets method inside a test?

I want to write an interactive spec, in my spec I login to a site, which asks confirmation sms. I don't know that sms code before I run spec, that's why I enter sms code during test run.

When I try to do something like `sms = gets.chomp`
I get the following error:

```
Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - spec/login/login_spec.rb
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rspec commandline variable input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609872/rspec-commandline-variable-input)

Comment: This question should not be closed.  The proposed is about how to mock gets in program code, whereas Vanya wanted to know how to call `gets` from the test itself, to get interactive input.

Answer (score 2):

In your spec you want to use `$stdin`.  Your code should look something like this:

```
it "sends an SMS and verifies it" do
  SMSVerifier.send_verification_code(test_phone_number) 
  print "Enter the sms code you received: "
  code = $stdin.gets.chomp
  SMSVerifier.check_verification_code(test_phone_number, code).should == true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of principle, `rspec`, and unit-tests in general ***should not*** be interactive. By actually sending an SMS in your test you need to:

- Have the relevant phone at hand
- Wait for the SMS to arrive (how long before you decide it fails?)
- Read the SMS and fill it (correctly!) back in your running test.

This means that your spec is not automated, and that instead of running it tens of times a day (as unit-tests were meant to be run), you will run it once a week, if at all, because it would be such a pain to run.

Leave live SMS tests to system tests, and unit-test this functionality by *stubbing* the actual send behavior, and check the received parameters:

```
it "sends an SMS and verifies it" do
  sent_text = nil
  expect(SMSSender).to receive(:send).with(test_phone_number, an_instance_of(String)) do |num, text|
    sent_text = text
  end

  SMSVerifier.send_verification_code(test_phone_number) 

  SMSVerifier.check_verification_code(test_phone_number, sent_text).should be_true
end
```

Comment: I agree with you, but my case was not 'general' rspec use case. I was writing a parsing script and I really needed to interrupt the spec to interact with browser (spec generally tests web driver based parser). In the end I choose to use debugger.

Comment: What you're saying is that this was not for unit-testing?

Comment: In development stage it wasn't. After finishing the parsing script it become a simple unit test, all the http requests were written with VCR gem and stubbing sms become not necessary